# How can generate Accessors fron entity in Doctrine2 using generate:entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am using this to generate getters and setters for my all classes in Bundle.

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities Acme/UserBundle
```

This is working fine.

When i use this , to update single entity then i get error

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entity AcmeUserBundle:User
```

Then i get error

`Entity already exists.`. But in the multiple entities method , my entities were still there but it updates them

I think there is issue with eingle entity generator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html), you'll realize that this behavior is exactly as intended. That command creates a *new* entity from a code-generation template in order to save you a couple of lines of boilerplate code.